# Internal micrphone is not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, microphone

I've just installed the Ubuntu 20.04. After that my builtin microphone is not working. Previously it was working perfectly with 18.04.4. Apart from that, I can hear the output sounds without any problem.

Here is my laptop configuration:
[image]
Here is the configuration of `Settings` > `Sound`
[image]

Comment: In my case I solved the problem with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1246507).

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/230893/20742) I got the solution. Use the following command couple of times

`pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`

The first part kills pulseaudio, the second reloads ALSA. It works for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please reload the alsa-driver:

```
sudo alsactl -F restore
```