# Ubuntu 20.04 Internal Microphone is not working. Input Device drop-down menu is empty in Sound settings

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Recently I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Acer Swift 3 laptop.

The internal microphone doesn't seem to work. Input Device drop-down menu is empty in Sound settings. But the external mic from earphones is detected and works fine.

Here are a few outputs that might be helpful,

```
reyansh@acer:~$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Conexant Generic
Codec: Intel Icelake HDMI
```

Multimedia audio controller output from `lspci -v` command,

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 164
    Memory at 601d160000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 601d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
```

Last few lines from /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf,

```
#Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
#options snd-hda-intel model=auto
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230283/internal-micrphone-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04) but no luck.
Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit 1:** Output of `sudo hdajacksensetest -a` (without external mic)

```
Pin 0x16 (Black Headphone, Right side): present = No
Pin 0x17 (Internal Speaker, Rear side): present = No
Pin 0x18 (Not connected): present = No
Pin 0x19 (Black Mic, Right side): present = No
Pin 0x1a (Not connected): present = No
Pin 0x1d (Not connected): present = No
Pin 0x1e (Not connected): present = No
Pin 0x1f (Not connected): present = No
Pin 0x21 (Not connected): present = No
Pin 0x26 (Not connected): present = No
Pin 0x27 (Not connected): present = No
```

**Edit 2:**

Output of `modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel`

```
reyansh@acer:~/Documents/Keys$ modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-dspcfg.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko model=auto dmic_detect=0 patch=hda-jack-retask.fw,hda-jack-retask.fw,hda-jack-retask.fw,hda-jack-retask.fw
```

Output of `modprobe --show-depends snd_sof_pci`

```
reyansh@acer:~/Documents/Keys$ modprobe --show-depends snd_sof_pci
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm-dmaengine.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/ac97_bus.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-compress.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soc/snd-soc-core.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/leds/trigger/ledtrig-audio.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-dspcfg.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soc/snd-soc-acpi.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soc/intel/common/snd-soc-acpi-intel-match.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/hda/ext/snd-hda-ext-core.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soc/sof/xtensa/snd-sof-xtensa-dsp.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soc/sof/snd-sof.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soc/sof/intel/snd-sof-intel-ipc.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soc/sof/intel/snd-sof-intel-byt.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soc/sof/intel/snd-sof-intel-hda.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-hdac-hda.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soc/sof/intel/snd-sof-intel-hda-common.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soc/sof/snd-sof-pci.ko
```

Output of `journalctl -b -k -p3`

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-04-01 22:53:42 IST, end at Tue 2020-08-04 12:10:16 IST. --
Aug 04 06:44:01 acer kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.DGPV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
Aug 04 06:44:01 acer kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.RP05.PCRP._ON due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
Aug 04 06:44:01 acer kernel: Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
Aug 04 12:03:52 acer kernel: snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: The codec is being used, can't reconfigure.
Aug 04 12:04:29 acer kernel: snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: The codec is being used, can't reconfigure.
Aug 04 12:07:04 acer kernel: snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: The codec is being used, can't reconfigure.
Aug 04 12:07:10 acer kernel: snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: The codec is being used, can't reconfigure.
```

Output Devices in pavucontrol
[image: Output Devices in pavucontrol]
Input Devices in pavucontrol
[image: Input Devices in pavucontrol]
AlsaMixer Configuration when earphones with mic is not plugged in.
[image]

Comment: what is the output for `sudo hdajacksensetest -a`

Comment: @rtaft I've edited the question with the output of the command.

Comment: Odd that it's not detecting it.  You can try `sudo hdajackretask`, select the sound card in the dropdown, then select `Show unconnected pins`.  From there, override either pin 0x18 or 0x1a, set the type to `Internal Mic` and `Apply Now`.  If it works I'll add it as the answer, sort of a long shot since it doesn't even see an internal mic.

Comment: Do you see some interesting in the output of  `modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel` and `modprobe --show-depends snd_sof_pci` ? Further check for errors/warning of the kernel: `journalctl -b -k -p3`

Comment: @rtaft I tried overriding the pins you suggested, I get the following error.
tee:/sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/rconfig: Device or resource busy

Comment: @rtaft output in the console. E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process.
0x16 0x04211040
0x17 0x91170110
0x18 0x90a60160
0x19 0x04a11030
0x1a 0x40f001f0
0x1d 0x40f001f0
0x1e 0x40f001f0
0x1f 0x40f001f0
0x21 0x40f001f0
0x26 0x40f001f0
0x27 0x40f001f0

Comment: @abu_bua I've edited my question, please check the output in Edit 2 section. Thanks!

Comment: Did you set special kernel parameter ? Print `cat /proc/cmdline`. There seems to be an error with your bios?, don't know exactly. Further: `Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed` is a known bug and harmless. A lot of paramters are set in the intel module; did you changed your `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file?

Comment: @abu_bua `cat /proc/cmdline` gives `BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=UUID=4ba44c51-9f1e-49ac-bbb7-887fe8e8a3ad ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7` as output.

Comment: @abu_bua In the beginning, even my speaker wasn't working, so I added the following two lines at the end of alsa-conf file

`options snd-hda-intel model=auto`
`options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0`

Comment: Also while I was installing Ubuntu I had to disable RST. In the BIOS settings, I changed the SATA mode to AHCI.

Comment: Sorry, saw it now that you changed your alsa-base.conf . Try to include `options snd-hda-intel dsp_driver=0` in your alsa-base.conf to load the legacy drivers.

Comment: Do you see any errors in `cat /proc/asound/cards` ?

Comment: No, `cat /proc/asound/cards` outputs ` 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x601d160000 irq 164`

Comment: adding `options snd-hda-intel dsp_driver=0` didn't change anything

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in the alsa-driver. See [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1793410), [mint Wiki](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=279424&start=47) and [kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201251)

At present the only option seems to be using an external microphone through USB post.

Comment: It's been two years and the bug is still not fixed? Strange!! Will it be solved ever?

Comment: The built-in microphone is not detected after upgrading ubuntu 20.04. Isn't this issue fixed yet?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly your problem but similar. In my case, laptop Toshiba Satellite L840, internal mic stopped working after I accidentaly plugged headphones in the mic port. Can't tell exactly which step fixed it, but here it goes.

1. Installed pavucontrol and reboot. (Didn't work)
2. `sudo alsactl -F restore` then Opened pavucontrol and changed the sound profile to another and back, and reboot. (Didn't work)
3. Plugin headphones in the mic port and reboot with it connected, now it detected at least a "wired mic", disconnected it, changed profile to "duplex internal audio" and that did it.

Hope it helps someone... Greetings

Answer (score 0):

I had an opposite issue where the internal mic built into the PC chassis worked but when I plugged in a 3.5mm headset, only headphone out was detected and not the headset mic.

Comparing the last few lines of your **`etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`**, the final line of yours is different to mine. Mine is also a `snd_hda_intel` device but does not have the `dmic_detect` line, and instead has the `model=` line un-commented, as follows:

```
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
# Shows multi-selection dialog. I added this to fix my headphone jack microphone issue
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

You can try various options for `model=`, such as `auto` or `dell-headset-multi` to see if it fixes your issue.  May need a restart between changes.

On my PC with the option set to `dell-headset-multi` (not just for Dell PCs btw, mine is not Dell), it will add either a dialog popup or additional combobox in audio settings (depends on how your Desktop Environment handles it) allowing you to select the microphone/headset depending on what is inserted.

If you set it to `auto` it should in theory automatically select headset when you plug it in, and then revert back to internal mic when you unplug it, so also try it and see.

Comment: I tried many such combinations, but no luck :(

Comment: why does input devices in pavucontrol not have the port option as it in Output devices?

Answer (score 0):

Reyansh,

This may or may not answer the question. But I upgraded quite recently from 18.04 to 20.4, too. And one of the first things I tested was the sound system and the permissions on same, because I need for it to work. So, one of the things I did was to run alsamixer, both to see what it shows me and to set whatever looked like it needed to be set. Because sometimes one even finds an input or an output setting which alsamixer says is muted, and then one should probably at least unmute it in alsamixer before trying some other, less basic tool. Alsamixer told me the microphone output was muted and was set to 0 volume, so I unmuted and increased the setting to a reasonable level, then tested whether it works. It did work. Of course, my laptop is not your laptop, so I don't claim I can cure baldness or old age. Treat this as a suggestion, and try it out if you didn't already. YMMV.

Comment: I tried tuning the alsamixer configuratioin, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Because of missing drivers - you could try this here :

> sudo apt-get install rhythmbox clementine

or

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall rhythmbox clementine

If this (after reboot) does not help, you could try to install these programs,
as described here (because of additional drivers) :

https://www.ubuntupit.com/20-best-music-making-mixing-and-dj-software-for-linux/

Comment: this didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Restart alsa-driver and check

```
sudo alsactl -F restore
```

This might be the reason

Comment: nope, didn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score -2):

I have faced external microphone issue for Kazam application [ref](https://askubuntu.com/q/1237885/1087660) . looks like in the latest python version some time() related API methods are deprecated. In my case Kazam application is not updated with the latest API methods by their developers.

In your case, It might be some internal files they are using the deprecated methods that might me the reason, not 100% sure , you can try below solution if you know the exact file where they are using the deprecated method.

[MicroPhone Issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/1246151/1087660)

Comment: This fix is for Kazam...not pulseaudio

Comment: yes, its Kazam specific, but we can troubleshoot the issue and find a solution, this is breaking because of some deprecated methods are used in the application and not updated to the latest respective version.

I faced this for Kazam application but we can check if the same issue is there for other as well.